# What is a good way to handle cookies in Pylons?

Tags: cookies, pylons, wsgi

I've seen a few references that say there is WSGI middleware to do it, but I don't know a lot about the choices for WSGI middelware that handles cookies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont need anything special with pylons (0.9.7), it all works out of the box:

```
from pylons import request, response

#set a cookie
response.set_cookie( cookiename , some_string, max_age=180*24*3600 )

#read a cookie
request.cookies.get( cookiename )

#remove a cookie
request.cookies.pop( cookiename, None )
```

Pylons uses [Webob](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/) (request, response) are (webob.Request, webob.Response) objects.

Comment: When I `request.cookies.pop(cookiename)`, the cookie still appears in Chrome's view of localhost's cookies. Also, repeated GETs to a page that calls `request.cookies.pop()` lists that cookie as being in `request.cookies`. I don't get that this really removes the cookie from the server/application. On the other hand, `response.set_cookie(key, max_age=0)` makes the cookie disappear from the set of cookies.

Answer (score 6):

The .pop above should be

```
response.delete_cookie('cookie_name')
```